# The method '_activityForm' isn't defined for the type '_QuoteListState'

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I've been trying to make a simple popup window using flutter, and I wanted to separate the popup window widget to a separate class, and I get this error:

**error:**

```
The method '_activityForm' isn't defined for the type '_QuoteListState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named '_activityForm'.
```

**form.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class _activityForm extends StatelessWidget {
  //const _activityForm({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Add Activity'),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          child: Text('ADD'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'form.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: QuoteList(),
));

class QuoteList extends StatefulWidget {
  const QuoteList({super.key});

  @override
  State<QuoteList> createState() => _QuoteListState();
}

class _QuoteListState extends State<QuoteList> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Lista'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[300],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
            context: context, 
            builder:(context) => _activityForm(),
          );
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[300],
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Why does this happen?
Could someone help me with this problem?

Also how to avoid getting stuck like this in the future?

Comment: please change _activityForm to activityForm

Comment: thanks! it works now. Could you explain why was that an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The method '_activityForm' isn't defined for the type '_QuoteListState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named '_activityForm'.
```

Concept is basically use of "_" an access modifier. Now you defined _activityForm as a top-level private class. These classes in dart language cannot be accessed in other files. You can use _activityForm Class if its in the same file.